# Array Object and Ordinary object Initialization

Tags: java, arrays

I have 3 objects `root1,root2,root3` where they are present in `root[]` (Array Object) which is a collection of objects.

I have initialized the `Node`  class using `root[0]`. So 
I am able to access the value of `Node` class through `root[0].data` but I am expecting `root1.data`should also access the same class because `root[0]=root1`, but I am not able to access the value.

Is there anything I need to do in order to work my logic?
I have the following program:

```
class a
{
static Node root1,root2,root3;
public static void main(String args[])
{
Node root[]={root1,root2,root3};
for(int i=0;i<root.length;i++)
    root[i]=new Node(value,null);
    System.out.println(root[i].data);//It is printing Correctly
    System.out.println(root1.data);//It is printing null value

}
public static class Node
{
 int value;
 Node next;
 Node(int value,Node next)
    {
        this.value=value;
        this.next=next;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile, let alone behave as described. What is `value`? What is `temp`? How can it print a null value for a field reached via a null pointer?

Answer (score 1):

> I have 3 objects root1,root2,root3

No you don't. You have three *variables,* and they are all null.

> where they are present in `root[]`

Nothing is present in `root[]` except three nulls when you initialize it.

> I have initialized the `Node` class using `root[0]`

You have *instantiated* the `Node` class, and stored the reference into `root[0]`.

```
// It is printing null value.
```

With this code it should be throwing `NullPointerException`.

```
root[0]=root1
```

No it doesn't. You overwrote it in your loop, and in any case when you did the (pointless) array initialization, `root1` was null, as you didn't initialize it.

Comment: sorry it was a root[i]=new Node(value,null); and not root[i]=new temp(value,null);

Comment: Don't tell me: fix your question. Several other things wrong with it.